# How to remove a certain row from DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

How do i achieve simple sql query like

```
delete from Users where userCity='Munich'
```

with DataTables ?

p.s. without using Linq or something like that simply because i do not use it though project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DataRow[] rows;
rows=dataTable.Select("userCity = 'Munich'");
foreach(DataRow r in rows)
r.Delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataRow[] rows = YourDataTable.Select("Your Condition");
foreach(DataRow r in rows)
r.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = ds.tables[0]; 
DataRow row = dt.Select("the condition")
dt.Rows.Remove(row);
```